# Connect to websocket if cloudflare protection is enabled

Tags: node.js, websocket, cloudflare

I am connected to a websocket of some website using node.js and ws module , that usually works fine but recently they re updating something and than they enable cloudflare protection ...

So i get 503 server response when trying to connect

```
function connect_to_ws(failures) {
if (already_connected) return;
if (failures == undefined) failures = 0;
log('Connecting to "' + ws_server + '"...');
var ws = new WebSocket(ws_server, [], {
    'headers': {
        'Cookie': cookie
    }
});

  ws.on('open', function() {
    already_connected = true;
    log('Connected');
});
...
```